# understanding Batch normalization parameters model output

Tags: keras, batch-normalization

I am having below model
[image]

After creating model using keras according to above diagram and i have following model parameters

[image]

My question is  how parameters for batch normalization 1 we got as 784. To my understanding batch normalization has two parameters, and since we have 196 filters my understanding is that we should have 196 * 2 = 392, but model output is shown as 784. I am not getting how this value came here? Request to provide intution on how we got this value?

Another question is how do we calculate for batch normalization for GRU units we got batch_normalization 2 got 512 parameters. To my understanding GRU has three non linear functions for update gate, relevance gate, and while calculating new cell value. so Here we should have 128 * 3 = 384, but model output as 512. How this value came here?

Thanks for your time and guidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of parameters for Batch Normalization is four times the number of input dimensions in the specified normalization axis (by default the last). This corresponds to the gamma and beta parameters, as well as the moving mean and moving variances. You can confirm this in the [keras' source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/normalization.py#L105).

To get 784 BN params, you have a dimensionality of 784 / 4 = 196 elements, corresponding to the layer before your first BN layer. For the GRU layer you have 128 input dimensions to BN, requiring 128 x 4 = 512 parameters.